# Issue creating route with optional param

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-core

I have the following decorator:

```
[HttpGet("{parameterType}/{parameter}/{product: int?}")]
```

and the function header is the following:

```
public IActionResult GetServices(int parameterType, string parameter, int? product= null)
```

I just want to pass `product` optionally, but it is giving me the following error:

```
The constraint entry 'product' - ' int' on the route 'api/Service/{parameterType}/{parameter}/{product: int?}' could not be resolved by the constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver'.
```

How can I lead with it?

Comment: just remote : int? from decorator

Comment: @S.Petrosov if I remove it from the decorator then it will be a required param. (I testing it with swagger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to specify route constraint. Instead of

```
[HttpGet("{parameterType}/{parameter}/{product: int?}")]`
```

use

```
[HttpGet("{parameterType}/{parameter}/{product?}")]
```

Comment: it is working now. But just one thing do you know why is the reason that I can't receive the `serviceProductId` when I put it in swagger? I tried it with postman and worked ok, but in swagger I can't get the `serviceProductId`

Comment: @FacundoGFlores it's difficult to say without knowing about your swagger configuration. You may post a new question and add more info related to issue with swagger